# Ext JS weird behaviour when extending Ext.Toolbar.TextItem

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I'm trying to extend Ext.Toolbar.TextItem to create a simple clock.
Purpose of this is to be able to add clock to status bar in my application.
My extended class looks like this:

```
Ext.define('Urlopy.Components.TimeDisplay', {
    extend : 'Ext.Toolbar.TextItem',
    initComponent : function() {
        var me = this;

        var dt = new Date();

        Ext.defer(this.onUpdate, 240, this);

        Ext.apply(me, {
            text : Ext.Date.format(dt, "Y-m-d H:i:s")
        });
        delete dt;
        this.callParent(arguments);
    },

    onUpdate : function(obj) {
        var dt = new Date();
        this.setText(Ext.Date.format(dt, "Y-m-d H:i:s"));
        delete dt;
        Ext.defer(this.onUpdate, 240, this);
    }
});
```

I'm not sure if I do this correct, it works fine until I try to collapse a panel. My layout is based on Ext.container.Viewport.

This is error that I get: http://vimeo.com/43978383

I don't know what's wrong :(

Any help is welcome!

**UPDATE**

This is my updated component:

```
Ext.define('Urlopy.Components.TimeDisplay', {
    extend : 'Ext.Toolbar.TextItem',
    initComponent : function() {
        this.callParent(arguments);
        //this.setText(Ext.Date.format(new Date(), "Y-m-d H:i:s"));
        Ext.defer(this.onUpdate, 240, this);
    },
    onUpdate : function(obj) {
        //this.setText(Ext.Date.format(new Date(), "Y-m-d H:i:s"));
        Ext.defer(this.onUpdate, 240, this);
    }
});
```

This now works, but when I uncomment 2 lines responsible for updating text all crashes :/

I get this error

> el is undefined
>   var id = el.id,

Comment: Try debugging using Firefox or chrome. that will help you better.

Comment: @AbdelOlakara I've tried it, but no luck, don't know what's going on. Could You help me with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11030477/ext-js-statusbar-with-clock, basically the same thing but different approach.

Comment: Could you replace the commented lines with console.log(this.rendered)? And tell us what happens?

Comment: Also what do you get if you replace the commented lines with console.log( this.isHidden() );

Comment: when I log(this.rendered) I get true, isHidden() logs false. Vimeo link shows that crash is only when I try to collapse panels :/ weird...

Comment: console.log( this.isVisible(true) )?

Comment: the same result - true and panels are working. this.setText throws that error, but I don't know why :/

Comment: Are you sure it's Ext.Toolbar.TextItem not Ext.toolbar.TextItem?

Comment: Yes, I've checked it twice :) in onUpdate function first line breaks my application. setText. Mayby something with scope?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try this and tell us if it still crashes?

```
    Ext.define('Urlopy.Components.TimeDisplay', {
        extend : 'Ext.Toolbar.TextItem',
        initComponent : function() {
            this.callParent(arguments);
            Ext.defer(this.onUpdate, 240, this);
        },
        onUpdate : function(obj) {
            console.log('tock');
            Ext.defer(this.onUpdate, 240, this);
        }
    });
```

Comment: And if you replace console.log('tock') with console.log(this), what happens?

Comment: It works, in firebug it throws object and all properties. I looks like I get error only when I update timer.